# Using only Rxjs, Single ajax request carrying two metadata request and providing responses in multiple view components in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

The scenario is, there is single service(data-service.ts)  having a method `getdata()` which returns `http.post(url)` ie it makes an ajax call when method is called.

There are different components like `abc.component.ts`, `bcd.component.ts`, `cde.component.ts` etc.They all created at the same time on a single page.

I want to do like below such that different components are sending different metadata like `clientJson`, `clientJson1` and expecting different data for different view.

***Is there anyway it can be done using Rxjs-5 purely? If yes,considering given Scenario,then, how?***

### data-service.ts

```
getdata(clientJson,clientJson1): Observable<JsonData[]> {
    console.log('Retriving Data from Solr Server.......' + JSON.stringify(clientJson));
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = "http://883.82./Ser/soSe"; 
    return this.http.post(url, clientJson,clientJson1).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

### abc-chart.component.ts

```
initData() {
    let clientJson = {
        "aoId": "M_AO_918",
        "viewBys": ["usstate"],
        /* ... */
    };
    this.DataService.getdata(clientJson,clientJson1).subscribe(
        success => this.abcChart(success),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
}

abcChart(jsonData) {
    /* ... */
}
```

### bcd-chart.component.ts

```
initData() {
    let clientJson1 = {
        "aoId": "M_AO_918",
        "viewBys": ["brands"], 
        /* ... */ 
    };
    this.DataService.getdata(clientJson,clientJson1).subscribe(
        success => this.bcdChart(success),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
}
bcdChart(jsonData) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: What problems are you facing exactly?

Comment: Thanks @rinukkusu, 415 (Unsupported Media Type). Charts components having metadata as "clientJson" are only getting data and they are drawn perfectly while metadata for "clientJson1" are not send and thus charts are not drawn.

Comment: However, if clientJson1 and clientJson are declared as below in both components, renders same data in both components.                  initData() {
    let clientJson1 = {
        "aoId": "M_AO_918",
        "viewBys": ["brands"], 
        /* ... */ 
    };                                                                                                           
 let clientJson = {
        "aoId": "M_AO_918",
        "viewBys": ["usstate"],
        /* ... */
    };   }