# How to use Rxjs and document.querySelector('button') in angular2 cli project

Tags: angular

Getting Error "Clicked NaN times". 
What is the correct way to execute  Rxjs code below?

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttleTime';
export class AppComponent {
    count: number;
    title = 'app';
    @ViewChild('input') button: ElementRef;
    // @ViewChild('input1') button: ElementRef;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
            .throttleTime(1000)
            .scan(count => this.count + 1, 0)
            .subscribe(count => console.log(`Clicked ${count} times`));

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use `this.count` instead of `.scan(count => count + 1)`?

Comment: so did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44922980/2545680) help?

Comment: yes thanks. Can you help in these (1) questions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942742/using-rxjs-like-forkjoinhandling-multiple-observables-to-carry-multiple-reques?noredirect=1#comment76861810_44942742  (2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826689/how-to-call-single-ajax-request-by-multiple-components-parallely-in-angular2-cli/44829500?noredirect=1#comment76795427_44829500 (3)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898818/using-rxjs-single-ajax-request-carrying-two-metadata-request-and-providing-resp?noredirect=1#comment76776111_44898818

Comment: you can then mark my answer as accepted, I'll take a look at those other questions

Answer (score 2):

You have to initiate your `count` field value in your class:

```
export class AppComponent {
     count:number = 0;
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Its working but Number of clicks is not incrementing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `this.count`:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
   .throttleTime(1000)
   .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
   .subscribe(count => console.log(`Clicked ${count} times`));
```

You're passing an initial value here:

```
   .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
                            ^^^
```

As [the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) say:

> You can optionally pass scan a seed value as an additional parameter.
>   scan will pass this seed value to the accumulator function the first
>   time it is called (for the first emission from the source Observable)
>   in place of the result from the missing prior call to the accumulator.

Comment: Its giving Error at count+1 using  .scan(count => count + 1, 0)

Comment: @ManzerAhmad Try `.scan((count: number) => count + 1, 0)` https://plnkr.co/edit/xqKWF2x6GLju8nOnADeg?p=preview